# Flutter CircularProgressIndicator Stroke Type

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, indicator, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I want to make a CircularProgressIndicator like an image. But I need to customize the stroke type. Is there any code example or library to change stroke type like the image?

indicator image:

[image]

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges